# Connect with TTcpClient through a http proxy

Tags: delphi, proxy, delphi-2009, tcpclient

How can i connect to a server through a http proxy server in delphi?
What about SOCKS5 proxy?

Google doesn't have any suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Indy (highly recommended), then try using a `TIdConnectThroughHttpProxy` object from the *IdConnectThroughHttpProxy* unit. It's a descendant of `TIdIOHandler`, so connect an instance of that class to your client object's `IOHandler` property. To connect through a Socks server instead, use `TIdSocksInfo`, in *IdSocks*.

If you're set on doing it manually, without the aid of a protocol library like Indy, then connect your `TTcpClient` object to the proxy server's address instead of the real destination, and then send your commands there. The proxy server knows where to send the request either because you issue a CONNECT command to it, or because you specify a full URL (instead of just the path portion) in the GET request. (The [HTTP spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2068.txt) demonstrates the latter.) The response you'll get should be forwarded from the destination server, unless the proxy server has an error itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it using Indy. You may find information [in the Indy in Depth ebook](http://www.atozedsoftware.com/indy/book/index.en.aspx).

Hope this helps.